# RabbitMmq on Mac can't start

Tags: macos, rabbitmq

I've installed rabbitmq on Mac OS X via homebrew, just a simple command:

$ brew install rabbitmq

but, when I start the server via  rabbitmq-server, it occurs:

ERROR: distribution port 25672 in use on localhost (by non-Erlang process?)

I want to find some process that uses port 25672, but I can't find that really strange

anyone knows the reason, thx a lot :)

Answer (score 6):

Use `sudo lsof -i :25672` to find the process. `sudo` may or may not be needed depending on user permissions.